# JSON.parse: unexpected keyword at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: magento2, javascript

I am getting this error in checkout. Below the Shipping Address form, Shipping Methods is stucked on loading. In console it says:

```
JSON.parse: unexpected keyword at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

process http://localhost/magento2/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor.js:19
getRates   http://localhost/magento2/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address.js:65
```

But, when I check there is even no model folder created under `http://localhost/magento2/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Checkout/js`

I cleared cache and deployed static content, but it's still the same.

Comment: check the ajax requests. one of them might not return a valid json.

Comment: the missing js files are not really an issue. If there are no files in the `pub/static` folder they will be served by the php script `pub/static.php`. the js files mentioned in your error are located in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/error-processor.js`. Try to debug the json object as Marius suggested